# Python: Call an object from 'n string value

Tags: python, class, loops

I sincerely hope this is not a duplicate, but I cannot find an answer (you'll notice that I don't even know how to ask the question!).

I have python code with one class and many def.  It would take too much time to explain why I would want to do the following, but I sure would be able to:

```
class A:
    def a(self):
         some argument

    def b(self):
         another argument
```

So to call the def's, I just put:

```
A().a()
A().b()
```

What I would like to do is have a third def that looks like this:

```
    def c(self):

         process = [A().a(), A().b(), A().a(), A().a()] #This sequence is just an example - there are many more def's.

         for i in process:
                  print 'Hello'
                  i
                  print 'Bye'
```

I don't know if this makes any sense?  What happens currently is the process part is called and the two print lines are printed several times thereafter.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: Does `A().a()` *return* one of those arguments, or just it does state it and do nothing with it?

Comment: Q: *"I don't know if this makes any sense?"* —A: I'd say no...

Comment: You're asking too low-level a question considering how not-obvious (or nonsensical) the question is. It's probably an [X-Y problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341). Trust us, as the answerers, to be better able to respond if you actually explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: What you are calling 'defs' are more accurately called 'functions'. A `def` statement is used to define a function. (Even more accurately, a function defined inside a class is called a 'method'.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might this work?

```
def c(self):

     process = [self.a, self.b, self.a, self.a] 

     for i in process:
              print 'Hello'
              i()
              print 'Bye'
```

In your original example, instead of storing the functions, you were calling them already when the list was built. The return values from your methods got stored in the list, so that is why they could not be called later.

Comment: I doubt it will be easy to understand to the OP without a slightly more elaborate explanation...

Comment: Ambiguous question meets lame answer.

Comment: Bemmu, thank you for your help - I appreciate it!  It is exactly what I was interested in!